# Is There An "Official" Way To Format A Degree On A CV?

Tags: cv, degree, bachelor

I've recently graduated (UK) and I was wondering if there is an "official" way to format my degree (and classification) on my CV?

Examples:

- BA (Hons) Subject (First Class)
- First Class Honours in BA Subject
- BA (Hons) in Subject - 1st

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't. Take a look at some of the resume's of your professors (they usually have a personal page with a resume) and pick the option you like most. Some things to note:

- Make sure to include the university
- Include the year of graduation, and the year you started as well
- Order degrees with the most recent one on top